# TextViews not populating with data from SQLite database in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Java, Android and SQLite, so quite frankly I'm amazed that I have gotten this far.

I am trying to create a simple cataloguing app for my bonsai collection which displays a summary of my collection in a RecyclerView on the MainActivity.

I've got the database working, in that I can add items to it (checked through DB Browser for SQLite). The trouble I'm having is displaying that data in the RecyclerView. Currently it is just showing the laucher icon placeholder image and not populating the TextViews with the data from the DB. The number of views that are showing in the RecyclerView correspond with the number of entries in the DB.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
Datasource mDataSource;
Button btnAddNew;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDataSource = new Datasource(this);
    mDataSource.open();

    List<DataModel> listFromDB = mDataSource.getAllItems();
    DataItemAdapter adapter = new DataItemAdapter(this, listFromDB);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAddNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
}
```

DataModel.Java

```
public class DataModel {

private String itemId;
private String itemName;
private String itemCommonName;

public DataModel() {
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

public String getItemCommonName() {
    return itemCommonName;
}

public void setItemCommonName(String itemCommonName) {
    this.itemCommonName = itemCommonName;
}
```

Datasource.java

```
public class Datasource {

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
SQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper;

public Datasource(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void open(){
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    mDatabase.close();
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String commonName, String scientificName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_COMMON_NAME, commonName);
    contentValues.put(COL_SCI_NAME, scientificName);
    long result = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    db.close();

    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public List<DataModel> getAllItems(){
    List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ItemsTable.ALL_COLUMNS,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        DataModel item = new DataModel();
        item.setItemId(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_ID)));
        item.setItemId(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_NAME)));
        item.setItemId(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_COMMON_NAME)));
        item.setItemId(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_SCI_NAME)));
        dataModels.add(item);
    }
    return dataModels;
}
```

DataItemAdapter.java

```
public class DataItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<DataModel> mItems;
private Context mContext;

public DataItemAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> items) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mItems = items;
}

@Override
public DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final DataModel item = mItems.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(item.getItemName());
        holder.tvCommonName.setText(item.getItemCommonName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName, tvCommonName;
    public ImageView ivProfilePic;
    public View mView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvCommonName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommonName);
        ivProfilePic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic);
        mView = itemView;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView object in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

TextViews and Image view list_item.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="Profile Pic"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivProfilePic"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommonName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Screenshot of what the MainActivity currently looks like:

[image]

Any other information required, just ask and I'll try to post it up.

Comment: When do you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter? I think you should call it after having loaded the new items from the database to the list. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() for further information.

Comment: Please read how to write [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jozef Dochan - sorry I hadn't seen that, I assumed that more information/context would be better. I'll try to edit down the code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, seems so simple now that I look at it.

In the Cursor, I hadn't changed the item setters to the correct ones after I copied and pasted the first line, just the column names.

Also I was identifying the ID column as a string, where it should have been an integer - also updated this in the DataModel class

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        DataModel item = new DataModel();
        item.setItemId(cursor.getInt(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_ID)));
        item.setItemName(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_NAME)));
        item.setItemCommonName(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_COMMON_NAME)));
        item.setItemSciName(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COL_SCI_NAME)));
        dataModels.add(item);
    }
    return dataModels;
}
```